# Добавить в проект ASP.NET сторонние библиотеки

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть API файлы.

[image: Список API dll's.]

Есть свой проект webapi **ASP.NET** на **.NET Core 3.1**. Как мне использовать этот API в своем проекте?
Пока есть только dotnet CLI и Visual Studio Code, возможности использовать полноценную Visual Studio нет, хотя и с помощью её интерфейса не совсем понимаю, как это сейчас сделать.

Comment: "Как мне использовать файлы своего проекта в своем проекте", чувствуете мощь вопроса? В нормальной студии в обозревателе решения правый тык на решении - добавить - проект - существующий проект, или как-то так. А потом `using MyProject;` и погнали.

Comment: asp.net и asp.net-core - это разные технологии. Какую именно вы используете? Не лепите лишние метки.

Comment: Вы хотите сторонние библиотеки к своему проекту подключить? Или использовать Web API? Тогда шлите запросы на этот api и получайте ответы (response)

Comment: @aepot API файлы - это сторонняя библиотека, а не мой проект.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ASP.NET-CORE. Да, я хочу подключить сторонние библиотеки, которые на скриншоте, к своему проекту. Т.е. сторонние библиотеки это dll файлы, а не файлы проекта.

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно просто создать в проекте ссылку (reference) на нужную библиотеку (не на все библиотеки).